# Changing from ng-route to ui-router $routeChangeSuccess is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
                switch (next.originalPath) {
                    case "/ac" :
                        $scope.currentTab = 1;
                        break;
                    case "/bp/:type?/:tab?":
                        $scope.currentTab = 2;
                        break;
                    case "/bs":
                        $scope.currentTab = 3;
                        break;
                    default :
                        $scope.currentTab = 1;
                        break;
                }
            });
```

I want to change the above code from ng-route to ui-router. I changed others to stateProvider and stateParams but no idea about how the $routeChangeSuccess will change is it to $stateChangeSucess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$stateChangeSuccess` instead of `$routeChangeSuccess` as per [State Change Events.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

> `$stateChangeStart` - fired when the transition begins.

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function () {

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, $stateChangeSuccess. See more from here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                switch ( toState.url ) {
                    case "/ac" :
                        $scope.currentTab = 1;
                        break;
                    case "/bp":
                        $scope.currentTab = 2;
                        break;
                    case "/bs":
                        $scope.currentTab = 3;
                        break;
                    default :
                        $scope.currentTab = 1;
                        break;
                }
            });
```

toState.url will give the changed url and can do actions related to that.